# System.net.http error in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Currently I'm developing Chat app,
and I had install System.net.http for my app,
but when I debug its shown this error in Xamarin.Android.

[System.Net.Http Error in Xamarin.Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EfTX.png)

Comment: Installed System.Net.Http version 4.3.0 from nuget manager, it works fine by my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you added the System.Net.Http.Extensions assembly (for example manually or by Nuget). But you might try to remove the assembly and then add it again.

Please also check the version number of the the System.Net.Http.Extensions assembly you added. Possibly you have added another assembly which targets version 1.5.0.0 while having another version installed.